# Conversion issue from string to decimal in redshift

Tags: sql, type-conversion, amazon-redshift

getting below error while loading data in redshift table.
Source column has string as data type, and target has decimal(7,2) as datatype.

Sample record of source:-

```
TOTAL_HOURS | REGULAR_HOURS
30.299997   | 30.299997
28.25       | 27.75
2.566666    | 2.566666
```

Error :-

> SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: Amazon Invalid operation: Numeric data overflow (result precision)

Query that I am trying  :- I have tried with numerous options however I keep getting the above error . Few queries that I tried are :-

1).

```
INSERT INTO schema.target_tbl 
SELECT  to_number(Total_hours ,'9999D99')  As Total_hours,
    to_number(Regular_hours ,'9999D99')  As Regular_hours,
FROM schema.source_tbl
```

2).

```
INSERT INTO schema.target_tbl 
SELECT
cast(Total_hours As float) As Total_hours,
cast(Regular_hours As float) As Regular_hours,
```

3).

```
INSERT INTO schema.target_tbl 
SELECT
cast(cast(Total_hours As Float) As decimal(7,2)) As Total_hours,
cast(cast(Regular_hours As Float) as  decimal(7,2)) As Regular_hours,
```

Answer (score 0):

I created two tables, like yours:

```
create table decimal_test1(val varchar);
create table decimal_test2(val DECIMAL(7,2));

insert into decimal_test1 values('30.299997');

insert into decimal_test2 select val from decimal_test1; --works
insert into decimal_test2 select to_number(val ,'9999D99') from decimal_test1; --also works
```

Both the last two queries are giving the expected results and inserting data into the table.

Comment: Thanks Yankee for your response . You are right . I had a data issue which was causing this . I was suspecting it as a conversion issue , but it was not .